# How to get each file's extension in a given folder in PHP on Windows XP?

Tags: php

E.g:

folder name:

```
myFonlder
```

files in myFolder

```
myFolder.01.mkv
myFolder.02.mkv
myFolder.03.avi
myFolder.04.mts 
...

// each file's extension may be different.
```

So,how can I extract the extension of each file?

Thank you very much!!

**[update]**

my own solution; want to know is it fast enough!?

```
foreach (glob("d:\\myFolder\\*.*") as $filename) {
    //echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";

    $path_parts = pathinfo($filename);

    echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
    echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
    echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
    echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
}
```

Comment: `glob()` will help. http://php.net/glob

Comment: You are right.I got it .Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('../moodle') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
}

?>
```

And use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php on filename

Answer (score 0):

This is the quick and easy solution on windows.

```
exec("dir d:\directory_name /b" ,$output); // in Linux dir will change to ls
foreach($output as $file_name){
$file_parts = explode(".",$file_name);
echo "File Name : ".$file_parts[0]."\n";
echo "File Extension : ".$file_parts[1]."\n\n";
}
```

Enjoy..!!

Comment: I found that the glob() is much faster than exec("dir d:\directory_name /b" ,$output);